# как запретить переход на страницу login.php,если пользователь авторизирован?

Tags: php

Недавно начал учить php. Нужно запретить переход на страницу авторизации,если пользователь уже прошел авторизацию
Help:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разбираться. Во-первых страница не авторизации а аутентификации или страница логина (хотя часто неправильно говорят авторизации). Что происходит на странице логина?

1. Пользователь вводит своё имя и пароль;
2. Ваша программа проверяет, что имя есть в списке пользователей, а пароль соответствует паролю этого пользователя;
3. Ваша программа генерирует уникальный идентификатор (id сессии) и сохраняет на стороне сервера соответствие id сессии - идентификатор пользователя;
4. Программа отдаёт пользователю только id сессии;
5. Теперь пользователь должен на каждый свой запрос передавать этот id сессии (чтобы это работало автоматически, на 4 шаге id сессии передаётся в заголовке Set-Cookie).

Вся эта схема работает с помощью [функций для работы с сессиями](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php). Если вы уже реализовали аутентификацию, то большая часть работы сделана.

Теперь посмотрите, как вы понимаете, что пользователь уже прошёл аутентификацию. Пользователь в каждом запросе (в заголовке Cookie) передаёт свой уникальный id сессии, а у вас на сервере хранится соответствие id сессии и идентификатора пользователя. Это значит, что вы точно знаете какой пользователь сделал этот запрос.

Если вы знаете что это за пользователь, то вы можете принять решение у себя в коде показывать пользователю страницу или нет.

Вот как это может выглядеть (очень упрощённо):

```
<?php // login.php

session_start();

// в самом начале принимаем решение показывать пользователю страницу или нет
$userId = $_SESSION['userId']?? null;
if ($userId) {
    header('Location: /');
    exit(0);
}

$formValues = [
    'login' => '',
];
$formErrors = [];

$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($httpMethod === 'POST') { // если запросили страницу методом POST (отправили форму)

    $login = $_POST['login']?? '';
    if (empty($login)) {
        $formErrors[] = 'Обязательно укажите логин';
    } else {
        $formValues['login'] = $login;
    }

    $password = $_POST['password']?? '';
    if (empty($password)) {
        $formErrors[] = 'Обязательно укажите пароль';
    }

    if (empty($formErrors)) {
        if ($login === 'admin' && $password === 'passw0rd') {
            // пользователь и пароль совпадают, логиним и сообщаем пользователю, что ему надо перейти на главную
            $_SESSION['userId'] = 'admin';
            header('Location: /');
            exit(0);
        } else {
            $formErrors[] = 'Неверный логин или пароль';
        }
    }

}

?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php if ( ! empty($formErrors)): ?>
        <div>
            <?php foreach ($formErrors as $error): ?>
                <div><?= htmlspecialchars($error) ?></div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label>
                логин
                <input name="login" type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($formValues['login']) ?>">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                пароль
                <input name="password" type="password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">
                Войти
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Логика может быть такой: При авторизации у Вас должна выставляться метка - кука или сессионная.

Вы проверяете наличие такой метки, и, в зависимости от ее наличия/отсутствия, перенаправляете или не перенаправляете на страницу авторизации.

Хорошим тоном будет установить куку с нужным Вам временем жизни и иными параметрами https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if($user->isAuth()){ //предположим есть какая то функция которая проверяет авторизован пользователь или нет
    header('Location: /'); //если возвращает true, то делается редирект на главную
}
```